# in how many ways a $5\times5$ grid can be painted so that painted cells form a T-tetromino?

Tags: combinatorics

My first question here..sorry if I'm not very specific but I try to be.

A T-tetromino has three connected blocks in a line and another one above the middle block. How many ways can one be painted on the grid if orientation matters? What about if it doesn't?

Comment: Do you mean like a [tetris T-block](http://images.cdn.stuff.tv/sites/stuff.tv/files/styles/big-image/public/tetris-review-T-piece.jpg?itok=iq0XpUw2)? In that exact orientation, or could it be rotated?

Comment: Yes, It didn't say anything about orientation. So it must be in that exact orientation.. the pattern something like this. If links are allowed here  http://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/egamia/images/a/a4/T_Tetris_Block.GIF/revision/latest%253Fcb%253D20060519115602&imgrefurl=http://gaming.wikia.com/wiki/Tetris&h=100&w=150&tbnid=MpGvnRAAFfKZ_M:&docid=Y1LrQ5iTHJINEM&ei=A809Vs_FIYXcUbzig_AC&tbm=isch&ved=0CB4QMygCMAJqFQoTCI_TjYyI_sgCFQVuFAodPPEALg

Comment: @bhd just say tetris rather than (more confusing) explanation

Comment: so that isnt done by brutefocing ?

Comment: Yes tetris, thanks for correcting me.

Comment: @bhd so ... may you edit your post to show what is the pattern descibed and moreover its oientation ?

Comment: Thanks for the replies @Agawa001, sure, iwill mention that it's a tetris.

Comment: another question that you would like to add an explanation in that contetxt, are the edging tetris-cells interleaved or intersected inbetween ?

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I dont think it's so vague. Yeah the edges are intersected as shown in the image.

Comment: Got an answer from somewhere, it says that the whole tetris can be painted in 12 ways by that pattern and as this can be done in 4 directions, hence 4*12=48!

Comment: Why should there be any solutions at all? 25 is not divisible by 4.

Comment: @bhd i notified you if the directions are all same or independant, plz respond, and dont type the exclamation mark at the end of a number, that gives it the appearance of a factorial

Comment: Yeah sorry, my mistake, I changed it right away. as I wasn't so sure about  the directions, added in the question  asking for both cases. Thank you for the time you put into this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume the point is facing up. The center can be eitherin the middle 9 blocks or the three middle ones on the bottom row. That means a specific orientation can have 12 ways to place it.

[image: tetromino placement]

There are four orientations, so the total is $12 \times 4$, or 48.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I can't get the first part yet unfortunately, can you be a little more specific on how exactly you come up with 12? I got confused as I've been dealing with these stuffs for last couple of days. Thanks.

Comment: @bhd Look at the center block. It can be in columns 2-4 and rows 2-5 if the T is pointing up. 3 x 4 is 12.

Comment: @BHD: Make it look like an upside/down T. The middle block can be either in the middle column or the ones to its left and right. That's 3 columns. It can be in all the rows except the top one. That's 4 rows.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm being idiot! can you be more clear? You mean the center block of T pointing up can be placed in 4 ways in the grid?

Comment: I got it now ! Thank you very much .. great help ! I'm really grateful for your time ...

Comment: @bhd No problem! Check the picture I just posted if you're still uncertain.

Comment: You're one of a kind! I had got it by your last comment, but now I can understand it much more certainly n deeply.. thanks a billion.

Comment: @SuperJedi224: There are four orientations. Each orientation has 12 possibilities.

Comment: @Super: Really? What's the difference between that and the sentences before and after the image?

Comment: I don't see any difference! @Superjedi224

Comment: I'll agree that each orientation has 12 possible placements, but not quite for the reason mentioned in the first sentence.

Comment: @SuperJedi224: Alright, can you explain how my first statement is not equivalent to the picture?

Comment: The center three cells of the bottom row are only a valid placement for the center square if the tetromino is facing up. If it is facing right, for example, those are no longer valid, but the center three cells of the left column are. Etc. I am not saying that your statement is not equivalent to the diagram, or that it is not true in that case, but that that is the only orientation in which it is entirely true. Additionally, it is worth noting that the sets of valid placements for other orientations are simple rotations of the set of valid placements for that one.

Answer (score 0):

Got an answer from somewhere, it says that the whole tetris can be painted in 12 ways by that pattern and as this can be done in 4 directions, hence 4 multiplied by 12 is 48 ways Any ideas?

Comment: that is done by bruteforcing, i dont see any mathematical approach to it, besides, are the all pieces follow same orientation? or their orientations ae independant to each ?

Comment: Thanks for the time agawa..

Answer (score 0):

Well, my study encompasses just the case where the orientation is dependent to each pattern, other case it is likely that no mathematical approach is valid and the solution is brute-forced.

[image: ![enter image description here]

From the picture above, see that each line contains minimally two tetrominos, where the red one fixed gives two eventual places for the other, 
which means there is $2^5$ in general.

When the blue tetris is fixed, just one position left, that sums it up to $3^5$ combinations with the fact that the grid is symmetrical (right to left), so there should be many cases to remove.

What is needing deep analysis is symmetricity, because amongst the $3^5$ ways of coloring the grid, these cases which are interleaving, or duplicated. so the only case where the symmetricity dosnt apply is the (red,green) couple, where the (blue,blue) and (red,red) couples are subject of being divided into 2, because one is vertically symmetrical to other.

- **1st case :** whene there is no (red,green) coloring in the grid

$U_0=\frac{2^5}{2}$

- **2nd case :** whene there is one (red,green) coloring in the grid

$U_1=5*\frac{2^4}{2}$

- **3rd case :** whene there is two (red,green) couples in the grid

$U_2=\binom25*\frac{2^3}{2}$

- **4th case :** whene there is three (red,green) couples in the grid

$U_3=\binom35*\frac{2^2}{2}$

- **5th case :** whene there is four (red,green) couples in the grid

$U_4=\binom45*\frac{2}{2}$

- **6th case :** whene there is five (red,green) couples in the grid

$U_5=\binom55$

---

- Summing all cases up gives:

$U_0+U_1+U_2+U_3+U_4+U_5=\frac{2^5}{2}+5*\frac{2^4}{2}+\binom25*\frac{2^3}{2}+\binom35*\frac{2^2}{2}+\binom45+\binom55$

> (I dont know how did you guys find the number 48)